# Graph Api Delta token is not returning correct data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to use delta query to get the changes in one of the rooms calendars, when i use the start date and end date to set the initial request, it returns the correct events data and then afterwards when I use the delta token next time to make request, but it returns event data with tag saying this particular event has been deleted and does not return any valuable info apart form ID.

Here is my code

```html
private async Task<IEventDeltaCollectionPage> GetEventData(GraphServiceClient graphClient, object deltaLink)
        {
            IEventDeltaCollectionPage page;

            if (lastPage == null)
            {
                var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>();
                if (deltaLink == null)
                {
                    queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
                    {
                        new QueryOption("startdatetime", "2020-01-16T00:00:00Z"),
                        new QueryOption("enddatetime", "2020-01-24T00:00:00Z")
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
                    {
                        new QueryOption("$deltatoken", deltaLink.ToString())
                    };

                }
                           
                page = await graphClient
                    .Users["nitroom2@domain.onmicrosoft.com"].CalendarView
                    .Delta()
                    .Request(queryOptions)
                    .GetAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                lastPage.InitializeNextPageRequest(graphClient, deltaLink.ToString());
                page = await lastPage.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
            }

            lastPage = page;
            return page;
        }
```

AS you can see this code will either look for dates range or delta token. so what I do is I initially make a call without a delta token, then once I get the final response I get the delta token. I restart the application this time and I provide the hard-coded delta token. Before restarting the application I also make sure that there is either a new event created or updated in the rooms calendar and then I restart the application with the delta token. I get a response back with some event data but that's telling me the event has been deleted, but that's not true.

[image]

Not sure what i am misisng here. can any abody suggest?

Comment: found any solution or workaround for these questions. Looks like its an issue on Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Not sure as i have not tried from long time. But had chat with Microsoft 2 months back and they did not know about this issue. not sure if they want to resolve it as this is here from long time and nobody responded here.

Answer (score 1):

when using delta query Microsoft Graph returns as deleted   new/updated/deleted items that are not in start-end date range of the initial request.

please check if that was your case :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32132602)

Comment: @abarazal - That was a normal review process, all questions and answers go through that.  The response is a canned one and is still valid.  Answers are required to have enough information with citations if necessary so that readers can verify that the answer is correct.  Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it's a question-and-answer site.  The purpose of the review/response is to improve the answer.  If I wanted to just criticize it, I would have downvoted it, which I did not.